# Automatic resize of center node of BorderPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have an application with a MenuBar, a Toolbar and a TableView.
Basically, my MenuBar and Toolbar is placed in a VBOX in the top node of a BorderPane, while my TableView is in the center node of the BorderPane.
My problem is: I would like to hide/show the toolbar and I assume that center node's height will be automatically changed by the layout of the BorderPane.
I did that in Swing simply by this:
`top.setVisible(false);`
but in JavaFX that seems to not work: center node keep the same size.
I found a solution but it's disappointing: I change the preferred height of the toolbar. See the code below:

```
public class Controller
{
    @FXML
    Pane        pane;

    private double height;

    @FXML
    public void handleButton()
    {
//    BAD code: doesn't work
//      if (pane.isVisible())
//          pane.setVisible(false);
//      else
//          pane.setVisible(true);

        if (pane.getPrefHeight() < 1.0)
            pane.setPrefHeight(height);
        else
        {
            height = pane.getPrefHeight();
            pane.setPrefHeight(0.0);
        }
    }
}
```

and the corresponding FXML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="445.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
   <top>
      <VBox prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: gray;">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <MenuBar AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
                    <menus>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                        <items>
                          <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                        </items>
                      </Menu>
                    </menus>
                  </MenuBar>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <Pane fx:id="pane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: yellow;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </top>
   <center>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" style="-fx-background-color: green;">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButton" text="Button" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Is there a more elegant solution than there ?

Answer (score 3):

You set the top invisible by

```
top.setVisible(false);
```

that is correct, but if you want to free the space that is occupied by the component you have to toggle the `managed` state, too:

```
top.setManaged(false);
```

Or if you don`t want to do it manually every time, use a binding:

```
top.managedProperty().bind(top.visibleProperty());
```

Comment: I change for this:
    @FXML
    public void handleButton()
    {  
      if (pane.isVisible())
      {
 pane.setManaged(false);
 pane.setVisible(false);
      }
      else
      {
 pane.setManaged(true);
 pane.setVisible(true);
      }
}

Comment: Sorry for partial answer. This is the full version:
I change for this:
    @FXML
    public void handleButton()
    {  
      if (pane.isVisible())
      {
 pane.setManaged(false);
 pane.setVisible(false);
      }
      else
      {
 pane.setManaged(true);
 pane.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
but that doesn't work. On the other hands, it's not really what I want because pane object would be managed by the BorderPane not by me. I would hope that there is a mechanism like in Swing where this code work well.

Comment: JavaFX is not another Look and Feel for Swing, if you want to use JavaFX you will have to adapt to its API..